# Google Maps InfoBox preventing scroll

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using [InfoBox](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library) to display information boxes on a custom Google map, but when the user is scrolling around the map with dragging (ie. on an iPad or other mobile device, or with their mouse), attempting to drag **on** an open InfoBox window does nothing (ie. the map doesn't move).

Is there some way to allow the drag scrolling to continue, even while on an InfoBox? I feel like it should just be a simple option but I can't see anything in the documentation.

I've tried moving the InfoBox to the `mapPane` (instead of the `floatPane`) but it didn't help.

Comment: I tried the infobox sample in the [InfoBox](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library) and it is working. Can you post your code and other details like platform used, other settings done?

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing. Here's the basic sample from InfoBox. As you can see, when I tried to drag scroll around the map while in the box, I highlighted some of the text instead: http://imgur.com/t9CHZJS

Comment: I think it is the intended behavior, if you try to drag scroll around the map while in the box. You can try to do the same thing with the [infoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) JavaScript API, you will experience the same behavior.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Yes, I don't think it's a bug, I'm just looking for a way to change it.